# WKWebview iOS 11 Tap gesture + External link

Tags: ios, hyperlink, wkwebview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have added tap gesture to WKWebview. External link click event are not working after added tap gesture. DecidePolicyForNavigationAction is not called.    But everything works properly in iOS-12.  Earlier versions are not working.

```
 - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
NSString* urlScheme = [[navigationAction.request URL] scheme];
if ([urlScheme isEqualToString:@"http"] || [urlScheme isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
    // FOR HTTP/HTTPS TO OPEN WITHIN THE APP
ExternalWebBrowser* externalWebBrowser = [[ExternalWebBrowser alloc] init];
    externalWebBrowser.externalURL = [navigationAction.request URL];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:externalWebBrowser animated:YES];
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
}
return decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}


 - (void)userDidTapWebView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
//This method is calling always in iOS 11 and earlier.  Even I tap on WKWebview link. 
 }
```

Comment: Any one have the idea?